# Will handler automatically skip other runnables/messages when calling postAtTime

Tags: java, android, multithreading

From (Android Handler class)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postAtTime(java.lang.Runnable, long),
the description of the method postAtTime is "Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run at a specific time given by uptimeMillis. The time-base is uptimeMillis()." The parameter uptimeMillis is "The absolute time at which the callback should run, using the uptimeMillis() time-base". My question is if there are still runnables/messages that still need to be run when postAtTime triggers, will those runnables/messages just be discarded(removed from the queue). My question comes from my experience with queues: you only have access to the front of the queue, so I am assuming that that specific message/ runnable gets moved to the front of the queue. What happens to all the ones it skips over? API didn't address this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the time parameter as "no earlier than", not as an exact time.

The runnable is put into the queue and becomes eligible to run at the specified time. It is actually run only after any messages in front of the queue have finished processing.

For further details, you can [read the source](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Handler.java#sendMessageAtTime).

Comment: Thank you that clarified it